# Swift - UILabel text not displayed correctly

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, uilabel

I have no idea why my `UILabel` is not being displayed correctly but instead Swift shortens it like you can see in the picture below:

[image]

This is how I create the `label` and both of the `lines`:

```
let oderLabel: UILabel = {
    let v = UILabel()
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    v.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-DemiBold", size: 15)
    v.textColor = .white
    v.textAlignment = .center
    v.text = "ODER"
    return v
}()

let lineLeft: UIImageView = {
    let v = UIImageView()
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    v.image = UIImage(named: "line")
    return v
}()

let lineRight: UIImageView = {
    let v = UIImageView()
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    v.image = UIImage(named: "line")
    return v
}()
```

And my `constraints`:

```
    oderLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    oderLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: weiterButton.bottomAnchor, constant: 40).isActive = true
    
    lineLeft.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: oderLabel.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    lineLeft.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true
    lineLeft.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: oderLabel.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    
    lineRight.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: oderLabel.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    lineRight.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: oderLabel.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    lineRight.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -30).isActive = true
```

All I want is to center the `label` and have both of the `lines` with little bit of space next to it. And that should be correctly displayed on all iPhone sizes. I am on this now for way too long..

It should be a 1 min task so I probably have some misunderstanding. If anyone could help me out here I'd really appreciate it :)

Comment: Use the View Debugger. You probably have an ambiguity. You need to raise the content size priority of the label so that it keeps its size and the lines are what shrinks.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by that? In the View Debugger it looks like the `lines` are the reason why it shrinks. But how can I fix it? My understand is that the lines should just be displayed on top of the label if its overlapping but thats not the case

Comment: I mean raise the horizontal compression resistance priority.

Comment: how do I do that

Comment: Syntax might have changed, but it used to be like this: ``oderLabel.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(UILayoutPriorityRequired, forAxis: .Horizontal)``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a width anchor with an appropriate size to oderLabel might do the trick.

Comment: is there a way to get the labels actual `width` ?

Comment: I tried `oderLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: oderLabel.widthAnchor).isActive = true` but that wasn't working

Comment: Since it's a fixed text in the label you could just add a width anchor with a fixed size, like this: ``oderLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true``

Comment: alright that fixed it. Didn't want to have a fixed size but I guess it makes sense in my case. Thanks :)

Comment: @Chris If you create your label without a frame (using `.zero`). You can check its width after calling `UILabel`'s `sizeToFit`
 method.

Comment: This just wrong. The label knows its own correct width. The right way is to raise the compression resistance.